# Set elevation profile to CSV on ArcGIS Pro 3.x

Tags: arcgis-pro, csv, elevation, elevation-profile

I want to export my elevation profile analysis from ArcGIS Pro to CSV.
I am able to export it, but it seems that I cannot edit the interval of elevation values exported to CSV.

I want to have an interval for each 1 meter but ArcGIS automatically uses a 4.2 m interval.

Pictures are below.

[image: strong textenter image description here]

[image]